# Bad request biopython what's wrong

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Hey what's wrong with my script? It responds bad request. I don't know what's wrong

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = 'matro@gmail.com'
import time



  def fetch(ID):
        handle = Entrez.efetch(db = 'Protein', id = ID, retmode = 'fasta', rettype = 'text') #<--- here 
        seq = handle.read()
        time.sleep(1)
        return seq
  ids = ['ATK1','Cat','Lig1']
  out = [fetch(id) for id in ids] 
  with open('out.fasta', 'w') as f:
      f.writelines(out)
```

trackback:

```
File "<ipython-input-42-0be173f176eb>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/MGrad/bioPythonSearch.py', wdir='C:/Users/MGrad/Dropbox/Leg')

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Leg/bioPythonSearch.py", line 20, in <module>
out = [fetch(id) for id in ids] # where ids is a Python list containing gene ids/accession numbers

File "C:/Users/MGrad/bioPythonSearch.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
out = [fetch(id) for id in ids] # where ids is a Python list containing gene ids/accession numbers

File "C:/Users/MGrad/bioPythonSearch.py", line 14, in fetch
handle = Entrez.efetch(db = 'Protein', id = ID, retmode = 'fasta', rettype = 'text')

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site-packages\Bio\Entrez\__init__.py", line 180, in efetch
return _open(cgi, variables, post=post)

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site-packages\Bio\Entrez\__init__.py", line 526, in _open
raise exception

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site-packages\Bio\Entrez\__init__.py", line 524, in _open
handle = _urlopen(cgi)

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)

File "C:\Users\MGrad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Bad Request
```

Comment: Please post the full error/traceback. Currently you're relying on people knowing this specific library while it might be more general

Comment: HTTPError: Bad Request

Comment: That's 100% of the entire error that is reported? No traceback?

Comment: raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Bad Request

Comment: .... please edit the whole traceback into the question. That's the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entrez.efetch()` works with exact ID numbers.  If you want to lookup terms like ATK1, you need to go through `Entrez.esearch()` first to resolve that into one or more ID numbers.  Here's a simplistic, but working, example:

```
import time
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Entrez

import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree

TERMS = ['ATK1', 'Cat', 'Lig1']

Entrez.email = 'matro@gmail.com'

def fetch(term):
    # retmax=1 just returns first result of possibly many;  i.e. may be wrong, use more specific ID
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='Protein', term=term, retmax=1)
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(handle.read())

    id_number = root.find("IdList/Id").text

    print(term, '->', id_number)  # ATK1 -> 1039008188

    handle = Entrez.efetch(db='Protein', id=id_number, retmode='text', rettype='fasta')
    seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, 'fasta')

    time.sleep(1)
    return seq_record

out = [fetch(my_term) for my_term in TERMS]

with open('out.fasta', 'w') as f:
    for record in out:
        SeqIO.write(record, f, 'fasta')
```

The `Entrez.esearch()` results come back as an XML document so we use `cElementTree` to parse it.  There are multiple results to this query but we naively just asked for one -- you'll need to work this out by examining the multiple results or providing more specific terms.

Also, your code inverted the values for `retmode` and `rettype`.